# Running `mockery` changes the default format of `mock_interface.go`

Tags: go, goland

On my GoLand, I have both `go fmt` and `goimports` disabled, however, when I run the `mockery` command to re-generate `mock_interface.go` the format changes. It turns out that whether or not `goimports` and `go fmt` are on or off doesn't make a difference to the format changing during the re-generating process. All file watchers on my IDE are set to default and when my fellows run the same command their `mock_interface.go` files don't change format at all. And their file watchers are on.
To elaborate, we expect to see the auto-generated `mock_interface.go` to look like this:

```
import context "context"
import mock "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
import model "github.com/some/repository"
```

however, what I've got after running `mockery` is this:

```
import (
    context "context"

    mock "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
    model "github.com/some/repository"
)
```

Essentially, the imports look weirdly. Although it doesn't affect the coding logic at all, how do I fix it?

Comment: This would be more readable if you embedded the expected and actual code.

Comment: What happens if you run `mockery` on the same file from the CLI? Do you get the same results as in the IDE?

Comment: @dlsniper same behaviour. Basically it makes no difference running `mockery` either on a terminal or click the green triangular button on the interface file. After running other command such as `goimports` typically you need to to click on a source file to trigger the change but `mockery` doesn't even need you to do that.

Comment: @MarkMcWhirter thanks for pointing it out. I've updated my question.